# When #if DEBUG runs

Tags: c#, .net

I have this code in my C# class.

```
#if DEBUG
        private const string BASE_URL = "http://www.a.com/";
#else
        private const string BASE_URL = "http://www.b.com//";
#endif
```

What I wanted to ask is when does the

```
#if DEBUG
```

path in the code get executed?

Does it get executed

1. When I run up a debug session in Visual Studio?
2. When I manually run the exe or dll in question from the debug folder?
3. Any other circumstances I forgot to mention?

Comment: `#if DEBUG` never runs but influences the code compilation.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`#if DEBUG` It's a preprocessor definition.

It compiles when you define DEBUG constant. And yes, it's default on Debug Build Configuration.

**Visual Studio 2010 Project Properties:**
[image: Visual Studio 2010 Project Properties]

If `Define DEBUG constant` is checked VS will compile:

```
private const string BASE_URL = "http://www.a.com/";
```

Else (not checked) VS will compile:

```
private const string BASE_URL = "http://www.b.com//";
```

Comment: Excellent answer. This is still the case in VS2017.

Comment: In my project, checking or unchecking 'define DEBUG constant' makes no difference. Any if/else/endif statements will still work as if the checkbox is checked. Any idea why?

Comment: This [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18441421/6908282) mentions how you can a "custom Configuration" other than "Debug" & "Release"

Answer (score 14):

It's a preprocessor directive. The code in the DEBUG part is compiled when you do a debug build (more specifically when the DEBUG constant is defined). I.e. if you do a debug build BASE_URL will point to www.a.com. Otherwise it will point to www.b.com.

Answer (score 12):

VS 2017 actually sense the active configuration and for example will **gray out** the debug condition if the release configuration is selected.

[image]

Comment: very nice visual representation of this whole concept. A single picture contains 1000 words afterall :)

Comment: This is the actual answer.

Answer (score 9):

When you compile with the DEBUG directive. So if it's set only the first line will be part of the compiled binary and if it's not set the second line will be part of the binary.

The DEBUG is by default set when you are compiling the debug configuration in VS however you can set it manually for any configuration

Answer (score 4):

That is a "compiler directive", which means it will actually include or exclude the code from the build process (or compiling) based on the #if's that you put in.  That being said, the DEBUG symbol is in the properties of your project, and in Visual Studio is generally removed automatically on the "Release" build.

So basically, it doesn't have to be in Visual studio running in debug, and it does not have to be in any certain folder, your code is just built that way.

Answer (score 3):

If you are compiling with the DEBUG configuration, the code before the else line will get compiled while the other will not. If you compile in any other configuration, the second line will be compiled while the first will not.

Comment: True in the default setup of the projects in VS however not using VS or changing the setup might include the DEBUG symbol in _any_ configuration (including release if you so wish)

Answer (score 2):

Go to "Project Properties"--> Build Tab of the application. If the Configuration: Active (Debug) then Debug configuration is enabled. 
Below code will print to console.

```
#if DEBUG
    Console.WriteLine("in debug mode...");
#endif
```

If Configuration: Active(Release) then Release configuration is enabled.Below code will print to console.

```
#if RELEASE
    Console.WriteLine("in release mode...");
#endif
```

If you want to switch between DEBUG and RELEASE mode use the "Debug/Release/Configuration Manager" drop down right under the Tools Menu.Apologies as most of the developer know it...but is sometimes overlooked and causes confusion why above code is not running correctly.