# How do I automatically (un)comment code per assembly edition?

Tags: visual-studio, decompiling, comments, cracking

I have a project that compiles in to an .exe 
This project needs to be available in 2 editions. Everytime I perform an update, I need to comment out several pieces for "edition A" and vica versa for "edition B".

The reason for "(un)commenting" instead of just using a config setting or some context variable is because I don't want Intermediate Code from "Edition A" to be available in "Edition B" and vica versa because this would make the life of software crackers a lot more easy.

Is there a way in visual studio to add/remove code from compilation based on a setting?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need [Preprocessor Directives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx):

```
#define PI 
using System;
namespace PreprocessorDAppl
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         #if (PI)
            Console.WriteLine("PI is defined");
         #else
            Console.WriteLine("PI is not defined");
         #endif
         Console.ReadKey();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Looks like this is something to be performed per File if I'm correct? Thumbs up. See my answer to see what I've done. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Based on this SO post I found the answer to my question:

[#if debug --> #if myOwnConfig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441299/if-debug-if-myownconfig)

FIRST:

1.Build -> Configuration manager -> Active solution configuration -> New...

2.Create a new configuration "Offline".

3.Project -> Properties -> Build -> Configuration -> Offline

4.Conditional compilation symbols: type OFFLINE

5.Save project.

THEN , right click your project

1.go to Properties -> Build.

2.At the configuration dropdown, select "Offline"

3.Add "OFFLINE" to the "Conditional compilation symbols" text box

Result:

```
#if Offile
        MessageBox.Show("Offline");
#endif

#if NotOffline
        MessageBox.Show("NotOffline");
#endif
```