# What PLAT_BINARYFORMATTER means in C#?

Tags: c#, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I have a small problem with the library I am using(protobuf-net). I decided to checkout library project and I found something like:

```
#if PLAT_BINARYFORMATTER
            DoSomething()
#endif
```

The problem I have is that this code is working in some of the projects I have in the solution and in some projects it does not work. I guess the projects have different contexts regarding this "PLAT_BINARYFORMATTER" thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18441299/890890) answers your question.

Basically it is a custom **Configuration** like the default `#if DEBUG`. Just create a new configuration and you can get it with:

```
#if THE_NAME_OF_YOUR_NEW_CONFIGURATION
        DoSomething()
#endif
```

About your problem, **maybe you're running the projects with different configurations**.