# A StackOverflowException occurs on System.Diagnotics.StackTrace()

Tags: .net, iis-7.5, cassini, stack-overflow, asp.net-development-serv

I've been writing a web application targeted to .NET framework v3.5 with Visual Studio 2013.

Indirect recursion in it someties cause a StackOverflowException so I wrote a method which checks if the stack overflows.

```
public static void CheckStackOverflow() {
    StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
    StackDepth = stackTrace.GetFrames().Length;
    if(StackDepth > MAXIMUM_STACK_DEPTH) {
        throw new StackOverflowException("StackOverflow detected.");
    }
}
```

The problem is that a StackOverflowException occurs at the first line, i.e. `new StackTrace()`, so I cannot take care of it.

I know that calling to StackTrace() also deepens the stack by a couple of levels, so I understand this can happen. However, there is some food for thought:

1. Opting for *Visual Studio(ASP.NET) Development Server(hereinafter Cassini)* in Visual Studio 2012 got no problem, so my IIS settings or something like that is a suspect.
2. The stack, at the time the exception occured, was NOT really deep enough.
3. <s>This only happens on debugging. Regardless of the configuration(i.e. Debug/Release).</s>

---

**Edit:** I tried to [changed *IIS Express* settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12946477/1986241) and it made no differences. Also, Trying *Local IIS* option got no luck, either. So,

```
if(RunningWithVisualStudio) { // Start Debugging or Without Debugging
    if(UsingCassini) {
        throw new StackOrverflowException("A catchable exception."); // expected
    } else {
        throw new StackOverflowException("I cannot catch this dang exception.");
    }
} else { // publish on the identical ApplicationPool.
    throw new StackOrverflowException("A catchable exception."); // expected
}
```

I thought I'd made mistakes configuring *IIS Express* but now I'm totally lost.

Answer (score 1):

Here are what I did as workaround:

1. I added below to .csproj file to define the current version of IDE.
   [image]
2. [Defined DEBUG constant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12960644/1986241)
3. added conditions using preprocessor directives.

   ```
   public static void CheckStackOverflow() {
       StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
       StackDepth = stackTrace.GetFrames().Length;
       int threashold;
   #if (VISUAL_STUDIO_12 && DEBUG)
       threshold = MAXIMUM_STACK_DEPTH_FOR_VS12; // set to be a "safe" integer
   #else
       threshold = MAXIMUM_STACK_DEPTH; // the one in common use
   #endif
       if(StackDepth > threashold) {
           throw new StackOverflowException("StackOverflow detected.");
       }
   }
   ```

   Where the constnat MAXIMUM_STACK_DEPTH_FOR_VS12 is the manually-found-greatest number that causes no problem.

   Now, I can debug and publish the app without changing anything but still love to hear your opinions.