# Can #if DEBUG be executed after building in Release?

Tags: c#

There is a security discussion going-on at work as to whether the following DEPLOYED code below can be reached or "hoisted" into...even though it was built in RELEASE mode.

Thoughts?

**EDIT:**
I do "see" it in DotPeek - even after building in Release.

- However, the file is "grayed-out"
- Does that mean it won't execute?
- DotPeek merely "decompiles" the code...it doesn't show you what code exists in the mode it is built-in...right?

**THE CODE LOOKS LIKE:**

```
    using System;
    using System.ServiceProcess;

    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        static void Main()
        {
#if DEBUG
            var myservice = new StpListener();
            myservice.OnDebug();

            //KEEP the service alive
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
#else
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new StpListener() 
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
#endif
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you build both and have a look with dotPeek?

Comment: Not too familiar with dotPeek - does it have the ability to access PDBs and retrieve actual source files? If so, copy just your `exe` to another directory before checking the exe out.

Comment: (Or, just looking in the dotPeek documentation, it appears there's an option to *force* it to decompile even when it can obtain the source files - make sure you've used that option before drawing any conclusions using it)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Removing the PBD's did the trick...thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't confuse debug/release configuration with conditional code. It is entirely possible to apply the `DEBUG` conditional attribute to a release mode config.

Look, I'm evil!

[image]

See: [When #if DEBUG runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960602/when-if-debug-runs/12960644)

Answer (score 5):

It's a *compile time* feature. Once the compiler has finished it's job, you'll *either* have the code between `#if` and `#else` *or* the code between `#else` and `#endif`.

You'll never (so long as you leave those items in) produce a binary containing both sets of code.

Comment: You should also add that DEBUG may still be defined under Release in the project configuration, so it is actually possible.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - I took the question to be "can someone later, at runtime say, maliciously cause the wrong code to run?". If you've built a deployment that contains the correct code (i.e. the non-debug code), then by implication `DEBUG` was not defined during that build.

Comment: What if some evil developer in the team did #define DEBUG somewhere?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - then during testing, you'll observe that when you try to start this service through the Service Control Manager, it fails to start correctly. Since this code *either* configures the system to run correctly as a service or just runs as a console application.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using the `Roslyn` compiler (although in all likelihood this is true for all C# compliant compilers), `#if DEBUG` code will not even be compiled into `IL` so it definitely cannot be accessed.

If you use `Conditional("DEBUG")` however, the code will make it into IL and just calls to it will be removed, so arguably this could be a security flaw.

Answer (score 1):

[This Resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx) should help further explain, but preprocessor commands are evaluated at compile time.  Using them by themselves doesn't expose a security weakness, but that doesn't mean that the condition they evaluate can't be problematic.  `#If DEBUG` is more secure than, say, `if(Debugger.IsAttached)`.  You just don't want to make your `#If` responsive to a runtime condition (which would take some doing anyway).